# Creating Thread to print out message in finite counting loop

Tags: java

I am not asking for answer and i know this will probably get lot of down-vote but here i go.
Where do I start with this ? I have red most of notes i have on concurrent programming and still don't really understand what they want from me. do you guys know about any good tutorials ?
About the question do i use join, sleep or isAlive method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, check the example in the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this [Java Concurrency Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html) from end-to-end. Then you can create a Callable task and submit it to the executor. The responsibility of the new Callable task is to run infinitely print out the message...sample code below

```
while (true)
{
  System.out.println("I am going to print this forever")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you learn the [High Level Concurrency Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html) before trying to use the low level functionality.